# UIGraphicsBeginImageContext renderInContext Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, blur, uigraphicscontext

As the title suggest, I am having problems with the infamous rederInContext crash. I have read a lot of post online but none seem to give anyway on how to solve this issue nor anything that worked for me.

Lets start with common errors that I have already accounted for. I am using `@autorelease{ code }` and I am not getting any Memory Warning issues. I have also tried performing on the main thread, that didn't work either. None of the view's layers are null when they reach the statement. I have NSLogged them and they all are not null. I have tried a few various of my code and will post the errors that correspond to them.

**Attemp#1**

```
-(void){
    @autorelease{
            //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mapView.bounds);
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.mapView.bounds, NO, 0.0);
            CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextTranslateCTM(c, 0, 0);
            [self.mapView.layer renderInContext:c];  //Crashes HERE :(
            UIImage* viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            viewImage = [viewImage applyBlurWithRadius:4.0f tintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:0.55] saturationDeltaFactor:1.0 maskImage:nil];
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            UIImageView *newView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.mapView.frame];
            newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            newView.image = viewImage;
            newView.tag = 10;
            newView.alpha = 0.1;
            [self.mapView addSubview:newView];
            self.mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{ newView.alpha = 1.0;} completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
    }
}
// ** ERROR MESSAGES **
<Error>: CGImageCreate: invalid image width.

<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextAddRect: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextGetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextBeginTransparencyLayerWithRect: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorSpace: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

<Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorSpace: invalid context 0x1e432510. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

*** -[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1e432510
```

**Attempt #2** - Calling on mainThread

```
-(void)blurrEffect{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(captureBlur) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
-(void)captureBlur
{
    @autorelease{
            //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mapView.bounds);
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.mapView.bounds, NO, 0.0);
            CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextTranslateCTM(c, 0, 0);
            [self.mapView.layer renderInContext:c];  //Crashes HERE :(
            UIImage* viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            viewImage = [viewImage applyBlurWithRadius:4.0f tintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:0.55] saturationDeltaFactor:1.0 maskImage:nil];
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            UIImageView *newView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.mapView.frame];
            newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            newView.image = viewImage;
            newView.tag = 10;
            newView.alpha = 0.1;
            [self.mapView addSubview:newView];
            self.mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{ newView.alpha = 1.0;} completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
    }
}
// **ERROR MESSAGE**

malloc: *** mmap(size=1923772416) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
```

**Attempt #3**

```
-(void)blurEffect{
   [self performSelector:@selector(captureBlur) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}
-(void)captureblur{
@autorelease{
            //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mapView.bounds);
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.mapView.bounds, NO, 0.0);
            CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextTranslateCTM(c, 0, 0);
            [self.mapView.layer renderInContext:c];  //Crashes HERE :(
            UIImage* viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            viewImage = [viewImage applyBlurWithRadius:4.0f tintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:0.55] saturationDeltaFactor:1.0 maskImage:nil];
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            UIImageView *newView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.mapView.frame];
            newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            newView.image = viewImage;
            newView.tag = 10;
            newView.alpha = 0.1;
            [self.mapView addSubview:newView];
            self.mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{ newView.alpha = 1.0;} completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
    }
}
// **ERROR MESSAGE**
terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
```

I have also tried switching that autorelease code with the FXBlurView that have been posted around stackoverflow. That codebase also uses renderInContext and also crashes in the same spot.

Anyone have any ideas or solutions on why this is breaking and how to fix it? Any guidance or information helps! Thanks in advance!

PS:  If I were only supporting iOS7 I could use the UIToolbar but that blur effect looks horrible with what I am using it for and I am also supporting iOS6 so that is out of the question.

**Edit**: Added `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.mapView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);` and also tried to run code without CGContextTranslateCTM. Still crashed.

Comment: Is it on the simator? The 64bits one? The device? It sounds like you try to use an improper sdk release on ios7.

Comment: Testing on simulator but also on iPad Mini device. Simulator not 64 bit but iPad mini is.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know there was an infamous `renderInContext` crash. - Does it help if you call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` (I can't imagine why you wouldn't always use it)? Does it help if you omit the `CGContextTranslateCTM` call?

Comment: @matt didn't know there was one either until it happened to me and started to google for answers. More posts than I imagined. Also I am using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()`, just forgot to actually add it to this posts. I updated question with it. Omitting CGContextTranslateCTM does not help. The FXBlurView doesn't use it but still crashes. I also commented out the line and still crashes.

Comment: What is `self.mapView.bounds.size`?

Comment: @robmayoff Nice catch! Sorry that was just a typo, the compiler would have caught that. It is supposed to be self.mapView.bounds or self.mapView.frame.

Comment: map view comes with a special method for taking a screen shot of it, [MKMapSnapshotter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapSnapshotter_class/Reference/Reference.html). Is there a good reason for not using it here? If you do use it, does it solve the problem?

Comment: There was no catch.  A `CGSize` is the correct first argument.  I want you to tell me what value it has.  Try `NSLog(@"size = %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.mapView.bounds.size))`.

Comment: @matt Using Google Maps. I don't know if that changes anything but not using the MKMap. Also just want the be able to blur the image.

Comment: @robmayoff NSLogged `size = {695, 704}`